# React 17 - Adding Evergreen UI Pane Gives an Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

I am Getting Error in React 17 for using **Pane** from **Evergreen UI**
i had imported pane from evergreen-ui and using in my react js application it gives me error.

Following is my code

```
import React from "react";
import {Pane} from 'evergreen-ui';

function App() {
 return (
      <div>
        <Pane
         elevation={2}
         float="left"
         width={200}
         height={120}
         margin={24}
         display="flex"
         justifyContent="center"
         alignItems="center"
         flexDirection="column"
         >
          <h3>Elevation 2</h3>
          <p>Popovers and Dropdowns</p>
         </Pane>
      </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit useTheme.js

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import ThemeContext from './ThemeContext'

function useTheme() {
  const theme = useContext(ThemeContext );
  
  return (
    <div style={{ color: theme.color}}>Foo Bar</div>
  );
}

export default useTheme;
```

Comment: Still error is persisting, i think there is version conflict i ill raise issue on their git

Comment: Could you demonstrate the error on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/usecontext-ffkjd) or somewhere else?